# Получить максимальное значение глубины директории

Tags: python

Хочу узнать глубину директории

```
import os
src = r'C:\path'
for dir_name, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    print(dir_name, len(dirs))
```

Получаю вывод по всем поддиректориям, с указанием глубины каждой из них. А как получить максимальный но один вывод по всем директориям.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
max(len(dirs) for _, dirs, _ in os.walk(src))
```